# If a graphics card for gaming pc has a picture of a dragon is this haram or shirk

Tags: halal-haram, sin, shirk, game, doubts

I do not believe in dragons the Quran never mentions dragons (MSI GRAPHICS CARD) but I  want this gaming pc with a gpu they had a dragon and I realized it but I have doubts that this is haram and shirk and I would like to know if this is permissible I do not worship them btw.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think, personally, that this is 'haraam'. You aren't committing acts of shirk/kufr etc. However, on a similar note, this is not recommended. I have found a fatwa that relates to this topic in some form, so take a look and make your own judgement. By no means am I a scholar, or anybody important within the religion. I am in fact a recent convert/somebody who started to become more religious recently.

Look here: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/30921/ruling-on-wearing-necklaces-that-contain-animal-images

I understand that it is on Jewellery / Necklaces, but I haven't been able to find anything similar. I am not asking for clarification, only providing what best I can provide. According to said link, it says this: 'It is prohibited to buy and sell gold jewellery that contains images of living beings, not because they are made of gold, but because of the illustration attached to it.' This is for the side that says it is haraam.

Personal note: Do not take this as an 'answer', but I feel like it is not haram. It is not a sin to buy/sell items, because you are not trying to create something that compares to Allah's creation. You didn't even make the graphics card. Just peel the sticker off if unsure